# javascript function return date array for all Sundays in a year

Tags: javascript

i am writing a function in javascript that will return date array of all sundays.
below you can see my code :

```
function getDefaultOffDays(year){
var offdays=new Array();
i=0;
for(month=1;month<12;month++)
{
    tdays=new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

    for(date=1;date<=tdays;date++)
    {
        smonth=(month<10)?"0"+month:month;
        sdate=(date<10)?"0"+date:date;
        dd=year+"-"+smonth+"-"+sdate;

        day=new Date();
        day.setDate(date);
        day.setMonth(month);
        day.setFullYear(year);

        if(day.getDay() == 0 )
             {              
               offdays[i++]=dd;

             }
    }
}

return offdays;
}
```

the issue is that the returned array is giving random dates not the only dates for sunday :(
m i missing some thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you examine the result, you can see that it's actually not random. It returns the dates for january that are sundays in february, and so on.

The `month` property of the `Date` object is zero based, not one based. If you change this line, the function will return the correct dates:

```
day.setMonth(month - 1);
```

Also, the loop only runs from 1 to 11, you need to include december too:

```
for (month=1; month <= 12; month++)
```

---

Another way to do this would be to find the first sunday, then just step forward seven days at a time:

```
function getDefaultOffDays2(year) {
  var date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  while (date.getDay() != 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  var days = [];
  while (date.getFullYear() == year) {
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = date.getDate();
    days.push(
      year + '-' +
      (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' +
      (d < 10 ? '0' + d : d)
    );
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
  }
  return days;
}
```

Comment: Work pretty well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One bug:

```
for(month=1;month<12;month++)
```

That's just 11 months.

If you want for the whole year you need:

```
for(month=0;month<12;month++)
```

Because there are 12 months in a year. You can even combine that with Guffa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Month is zero based as like day, so if month is 0 then it Jan, So changed your code as below,

```
function getDefaultOffDays(year){ 
var offdays=new Array();
i=0;
for(month=0;month<12;month++) { 
    tdays=new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); 
    for(date=1;date<=tdays;date++)     {
        smonth=(month<10)?"0"+(month+1):(month+1);
        sdate=(date<10)?"0"+date:date;
        dd=year+"-"+smonth+"-"+sdate;
        var day=new Date(year,month,date);
        if(day.getDay() == 0 )              {
            offdays[i++]=dd;
        }
      }
    }
    return offdays; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function has error
error code:

```
tdays=new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```

replace to:

```
tdays=new Date(year, month, 1).getDate();
```

becouse 0(day) return prev month